# How should I indicate that my Python shell script is returning an error?

Tags: python, shell

I’m writing a shell script in Python (`#!/usr/bin/env python`). I’m a bit new to shell scripting in general, so apologies if I’m misunderstanding something.

My current understanding is that if my shell script works successfully, I should call `sys.exit()` to indicate that it’s succeeded (i.e. return 0).

If I’ve encountered an error (specifically, that the user has passed in an argument that I’m not expecting), what should I return, and how?

Is it okay just to call `sys.exit()` with any non-zero value, e.g. `sys.exit(1)`?

Comment: Did you try it?  What did you observe?  Please try it first.  After trying it, please update the question with your observations.

Comment: @S.Lott: He's asking about the convention, not how to do it.

Comment: +1 for asking how to play nicely with others. Note: I'm pretty sure the term "shell script" means "script written in a shell language". Just say "script" or "Python script".

Comment: @Tom: that’s a good point. I meant it in the sense that my script expects to only be called from the command line — not sure if there’s a term for that, or if that’s a good idea, design-wise.

Comment: @S.Lott: nope, currently I don’t have anything looking at the return value of the script. Just trying to avoid errors that I don’t understand in the future, in case a return value is important. I couldn’t find any easily-understandable documentation on the issue, so hopefully the answers to this question will fill that gap for others.

Comment: One minor point - when your script succeeds, it is perfectly acceptable to just "fall off the end" of the main module. Python will interpret this as successful execution and automatically provide an exit code of `0`.

Comment: @S.Lott: or, for the want of checking how a basic feature of Unix is meant to work, I’ll get very confused down the line when my script unexpectedly doesn’t work, and I’ve no idea why. Learning by making mistakes is a great principle, and really valuable, but it’s not the only approach you should ever take in every situation. And even if you believe it is, you’ll definitely be wasting your time if you try to make people follow it just by telling them to.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: Since you knew it was a basic feature of Unix, there's no real mystery to this.  Please try these kinds of simple things.  Have a little more confidence in yourself.

Comment: @S.Lott: thanks for the amateur, remote psychoanalysis, but I’ve got plenty of confidence. There was nothing to try here. I wasn’t checking the return value yet, and I had no idea how Unix programs reacted to return values. I just wanted to know what it was expected to be for errors. Obviously, I’m extremely sorry to gum up Stack Overflow with questions that are *just too obvious* for you, but as I try to make my titles pretty descriptive, you always have the option of *not reading them*.

Comment: @S.Lott: sure, it’s just that here, there was nothing to experiment with. I didn’t know exactly what return codes from Unix programs were used for, so I didn’t have any way of telling if I was doing the right thing. This wasn’t likely to bite me on the ass until the future, when I would have forgotten what I was doing when I wrote the script. Experimentation is great when you know what you’re aiming for and how to check it — I knew neither.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most Shell utilites have various return values depending on the error that occurs.

The standard is when exiting with a status code of 0, it means the execution ended successfully.

For other error codes, this is highly dependant on the utility itself. You're most likely to learn about error codes in the man pages of the aforementioned utilities.

Here's a simple example of the `ls` man page:

> ```
> Exit status:
>    0      if OK,
>
>    1      if minor problems (e.g., cannot access subdirectory),
>
>    2      if serious trouble (e.g., cannot access command-line argument).
> ```

It's highly recommended that you document properly your utility's exit codes in order for its users to use it correctly.

Comment: gotcha. Do you know if there’s a particular place where I should put the documentation of exit codes for my Python shell script? Is its docstring okay?

Comment: man pages, info pages, readme pages, docstring are all okay :)

Comment: @Paul: If you haven't already, you might want to check out the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) module.  A bit of a read but well worth it if you will be creating CLI utils which take arguments.  Argparse provides an easy way to present documentation when the `-h` or `--help` options are passed from the shell.

Answer (score 6):

Any non zero value will do. So `sys.exit(1)` is correct. These error codes are useful for using scripts on the command line:

```
python test.py && echo 'success'
```

The above will not print 'success' when your script returns anything but 0.